# ruby void value expression

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, irb

why I am getting void value expression error?

Code

```
[return 1]
```

And error from rib:

`SyntaxError ((irb):3: void value expression)`

same situation here:

```
def a
[
  return 1 if true
  2
]
end
```

Comment: because `return` doesn't have a value, none at all. But you need _something_ to put in an array.

Comment: Just use the values in the array; don't try to return from *within* an array value.

Comment: but why ruby interpreter does not allow me to use return in array, like in another example:
`def a(x)  x; end`
a(return 1) -- also void value expression, I do not understand it

Comment: Because it's non-sensical.

Comment: Because it doesn't make sense

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to construct the array, Ruby has to first evaluate the contents of the array. However, the contents of both arrays are a `return` expression which ends the evaluation of the method. In other words, the array will never be constructed, it is completely useless.

Ruby syntactically detects this situation, and makes it an error instead of executing useless code.

In Ruby, everything is an expression, which means everything has a value. However, for `return`, that puts us into a bit of a pickle: what should the value of the `return` expression be? Actually, it has no sensible value, because the current context is exited as soon as `return` is evaluated.

So, the value of `return` is assumed to be the *void value*, and whenever you use the *void value* in an expression context, i.e. where you would expect the value to be used further, that is an error.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to return a value that the parser can't determine.  This is because the return is in the midst of an array definition.

Better might be...

```
return [1]
```

Or

```
def a
  [(my_boolean_method ? 1 : 2)]
end
```